# Frobenius maps exist/do not exist for integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Does there exist an infinite ring $R$ such that $(x+y)^b=x^b+y^b$, and similarly for $2$ other odd primes $a,c$; **in which $\Bbb{Z}$ can be embedded** as a ring?

I have no idea where to begin.  Maybe someone knows the answer already.

Comment: So you want that identity to hold for $3$ odd primes?

Comment: It would appear tomasz and N.S. answered this question in the comments to the answer on your previous question.

Comment: By the way, a ring into which $\mathbb Z$ can be embedded is automatically infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT.** When does $(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$ in a ring? What would the characteristic of the ring have to be? Then you know something about the ring $R$. Given that knowledge, is it possible to have $\mathbb{Z}$ embedded into it?

Comment: "What would the characteristic of the ring have to be" $-$ the answer to that is not as easy as the original question. The only real issue is if it can be characteristic zero or not.

Comment: @anon True, but knowing that fact is valuable as well. Seeing farther is never a bad thing and it is not hard to show that the characteristic need be prime.

Comment: Seeing farther is valuable, sure, but I don't understand why this is phrased as a way to solve the original question as opposed to commentary or a challenge to go farther than the original.

Answer (score 8):

If the conditions were true for $R$ and $R$ contained $\Bbb Z$ then they'd be true for $\Bbb Z$. Could they be?